# Word meaning the opposite of "need"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need X. So, I can say:

> My need to X.

But, I don't need Y. How can I say that sentence using the opposite of the noun "need". For example what can be put in the blank in the following sentence.

> My ... to Y.

Comment: To be honest I don't even fully understand what you are asking. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is X a verb, like we need to talk? I might need to breathe, but I want to laugh.

Comment: @Sasan - There is not an exact antonym for 'need' (as you are using the word).

Comment: When asking for opposites, please say *what* is being contrasted.

Comment: "lack of need" isn't a single word, but maybe it works.  My "lack of need" to eat.  Wordy. "Because I didn't need to X" might work too.  Those aren't single-words.

Comment: "I'm sorry darling but my need for sleep tonight supercedes my usually fervent desire to make love with you until we collapse together, exhausted."

Comment: @Kace36 As other comments have suggested, "the lack of need" is the sense I am looking for in a single word.

Comment: @Lawrence As other comments have suggested, "the lack of need" is the sense I am looking for in a single word

Comment: @Sasan If you're looking for a 'positive' term (*it 'is' X*, as opposed to the negative *it 'isn't' Y), it might need more. For example, is the lack of need due to satiation or irrelevance?

Comment: There's no context, just the bare framework. Why don't you tell us *why* the English term "must" be a single word? And instead of letters like, As, Bs, Xs, and Ys use proper words, the ones you are going to use. Consider this: "I absolutely need a single-word" vs. "I needn't a single word, any idiom will do"

Answer (score 1):

"My need to X" is incoherent. I think you mean "My need of X".

There is no word that precisely means "lack of need". The closest I can think of is

> "My indifference to Y"

but that has other meanings as well.

> "My independence from Y"

is another possibility.

Comment: Couldn't you refer to "my need to eat" or "my need to apply for the job".

Comment: Yes, but that's with an infinitive, "to eat" or "to apply" . Sasan said "I don't need Y", which makes Y a noun (phrase)

Answer (score 0):

If I take your example "I need X" instead of "My need to X", then the word you are looking for is a verb.

What comes to mind is "dispense with". It is close to @Colin Fine's "indifference", but perhaps more proactive.

So:

> "I need water, I dispense with food".

The Free Grammar Dictionary gives the following definition and examples: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dispense+with

> dispense with
>   1. Manage without, forgo, as in We can dispense with the extra help. Shakespeare had this idiom in Timon of Athens (3:2): "Men must learn now with pity to dispense." [c. 1600]
>   2. Get rid of, do away with, as in The European Union is trying to dispense with tariff barriers. [Late 1500s]
>   3. Exempt one from a law, promise, or obligation, as in He asked the court to dispense with swearing on the Bible. This usage originally applied to religious obligations (to which the Pope granted dispensation). [Early 1500s]

If, however, I take your example of "My need to X", then quite honestly I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

**sufficiency**

> An adequate amount of something, especially of something essential. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sufficiency)

"My sufficiency of good food".

BTW, I like Colin's answer too.